# Is there a generic Composable lifecycle callback listener as like FragmentLifecycleCallbacks & ActivityLifecycleCallbacks?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-lifecycle

For debugging purposes, I'm trying to print the Composable method names upon their invocation without modifying the code. For Activities and Fragments, we can conveniently use ActivityLifecycleCallbacks and FragmentLifecycleCallbacks at the application level to debug the current screen's activity and fragment information. Is there a similar method available for Jetpack Compose?

Comment: @AbdulMateen no not yet